# Embedding Helvetica Neue DeskInterface font with iText

Tags: macos, pdf, itext, osx-yosemite, truetype

I am trying to embed the ".Helvetica Neue DeskInterface" (the system font on Mac OS X Yosemite) font in my PDF document. However the document comes up with no text although the font is seemingly embedded in the document.

I've tried different encodings but nothing works. Here's a code snippet that reproduces the issue:

```
package itext;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class LucidaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException,
            IOException {
        String[] encodings = new String[] { BaseFont.CP1250, BaseFont.CP1252,
                BaseFont.CP1257, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.MACROMAN, };

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                "document.pdf"));
        document.open();
        String text = "Some simple text";

        document.add(new Paragraph(text));

        for (int i = 0; i < encodings.length; i++) {
            String encoding = encodings[i];
            BaseFont helvetica = BaseFont
                    .createFont(
                            "/System/Library/Fonts/HelveticaNeueDeskInterface.ttc,0",
                            encoding, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
            Font font1 = new Font(helvetica, 12);
            char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
            for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
                if (!helvetica.charExists(chars[j]))
                    System.out.println("Encoding " + encoding
                            + ", char not found: " + chars[j]);
            }
            document.add(new Paragraph(text + ", encoding " + encoding, font1));
        }
        document.close();
    }
}
```

The result is a document with no text for paragraphs that use the font, although charExists returns true for all characters, and the font show as being embedded.

I know that the font can actually be embedded in PDF. For example if I use Safari to print to PDF a page with "-apple-system" font set in CSS, the produced document does use the font correctly, and the font shows in the list:

```
<< /Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /HNUAPP+.HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Bold
<< /Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /SIHBJH+.HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular
<< /Type /FontDescriptor /FontName /LCFIMY+.HelveticaNeueDeskInterface-Regular
```

So is this some known problem with this font and iText? I've tried other .ttc fonts and those seem to work, however I really need this one.

Comment: The font file name extension seems to indicate some font collection format. Have you tried exporting your desired font into a single ttf file and using that?

Comment: What tool should I use on Mac OS X to do that? Doesn't iText support .ttc files directly?

Comment: I've spent more time debugging this issue. It looks like iText does indeed support .ttc files, however it doesn't handle all the possible cases when loading "cmap" tables. In this particular case the Platform ID is 0 and Encoding ID is 1 and this combination is ignored completely by iText. The true type font loading code looks really old and messy too.

Comment: And that's why it's being rewritten. If you are a customer, please contact your account manager at iText Software to get a preview of the next iText version (which might be kept closed source; whether or not we'll release new functionality as open source is still under discussion).